# Powershell split text file into pages by delimiter

Tags: powershell, split, automation

New to PowerShell here. Have a large text file with many similar pages overlapping at the moment.  Wish to use the delimiter: "TESTING/TEST SYSTEM" which appears at the top of every page to separate them into individual pages. The raw original source always have a 1 and 0. 1 on the first line, then 0 on the second line, probably off some old mainframe system, I do not wish to use the 1 and 0 as delimiter, as I have other files I wish to run this command against with different delimiter, which do not have 1 and 0.

Here's what I found so far on StackOverflow, and is partially working:

```
(Get-Content -Raw inFile.txt) -split '(TESTING/TEST SYSTEM)'|
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { 'c:\test\outFile{0}.txt' -f $script:index++ }
```

However, this keeps creating two extra files. First file only contains those 1 and 0.  Second file actually contains the delimiter, striped from the rest of the content of each page.  The third file has the rest of the content.  This repeats till all the pages are separated, creating 3 pages for each section. I just need the delimiter to be part of each page.  The 1 and 0 can be part of it as well, or removed, whichever is easier.  Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
(Get-Content -Raw inFile.txt) -split '(?=TESTING/TEST SYSTEM)' |
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { 'c:\test\outFile{0}.txt' -f $script:index++ }
```

Note:

- `-split` invariably matches something *before* the first separator match; if the input *starts* with a separator, the first array element returned is `''` (the empty string).

  - If no other tokens are empty, or if it is acceptable / desired to eliminate all empty tokens, you can simply append `-ne ''` to the `-split` operation.
- If you want to make splitting case-*sensitive*, use `-csplit` instead of `-split`.
- If you wan to ensure that the regex only matches *at the start of a line*, use 
  `'(?m)(?=^TESTING/TEST SYSTEM)'`
- `(?=...)` in the separator regex is a (positive) *look-ahead assertion* that causes the separator to be *included as part of each token*, as explained below.

---

The binary form of the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator:

- By default *excludes* what the (first) RHS operand - the separator regex - matches from the array of tokens it returns:

  ```sh
  'a@b@c' -split '@' # -> 'a', 'b', 'c'
  ```
- If you use a *capture group* (`(...)`) in the separator regex, what the capture group matches is *included* in the return array, as *separate tokens*:

  ```sh
  'a@b@c' -split '(@)' # -> 'a', '@', 'b', '@', 'c'
  ```
- If you want to include what the separator regex matches *as part of each token*, you must use a *look-around assertion*:

  - With a look-*ahead* assertion (`(?=...)`) at the *start* of each token:

    ```sh
    'a@b@c' -split '(?=@)' # -> 'a', '@b', '@c'
    ```
  - With a look-*behind* assertion (`(?<=...)`) at the *end* of each token:

    ```sh
    'a@b@c' -split '(?<=@)' # -> 'a@', 'b@', 'c'
    ```

Comment: `Get-Content inFile.txt -Delimiter 'TESTING/TEST SYSTEM'` could be used in theory too if we had an example of what OP has and wants

Comment: @Santiago `Get-Content -Delimiter` is a convenient option for _verbatim_ delimiter strings that _needn't be anchored_, when the separator (delimiter)  should _not_ be included in the tokens returned. Here, we know that the separators _should_ be included, so it isn't an option. (Note that there's a _bug_ in _Windows PowerShell_ that actually mistakenly causes the _trailing_ separator to be included, but this shouldn't be relied on, especially given that it has since been fixed in PowerShell Core - see [GitHub issue #3706](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3706).)

Comment: Thank you, this is working for me:
  (Get-Content -Raw TEST.txt) -split '(?=TESTING/TEST SYSTEM)'| 
  Set-Content -LiteralPath { 'c:\temp\test\File{0}.txt' -f $script:index++ }
  == its producing file outputs starting from single digits to two then three, like this:
  file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt....
  How do i get it to produce file001.txt, file002.txt,...file101.txt,..etc...
  
  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @dudesowetodit. To left-pad the sequence numbers with zeros to 3 digits, use `'c:\test\outFile{0:000}.txt' -f $script:index++`

Comment: Thank you MKLEMENT0!!!  I've learned so much from this.  Appreciate your help.